# Is true that $F(H)\otimes F(H)\cong F(H)$? where $F(H)$ is the full fock space of Hilbert space $H$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, quantum-mechanics

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Define the full fock space $F(H)=\bigoplus\limits_{n=0}^\infty H^{\otimes n}$ where $H^{\otimes 0}=\Bbb{C}\Omega$, $\Omega$ is an element of $H$ of unit norm. Let us define the map $\phi:F(H)\otimes F(H)\to F(H)$ by
$$\phi((a\Omega\oplus x_1\oplus x_2\oplus\cdots)\otimes(b\Omega\oplus y_1\oplus y_2\oplus\cdots))=ab\Omega\oplus (a y_1+b x_1)\oplus (a y_2+x_1\otimes y_1+b x_2)\oplus\cdots$$

I think this $\phi$ defines the unitary operator between $F(H)\otimes F(H)$ and $F(H)$. I can verify that $\phi$ preserves inner product and it is onto since $\phi((a\Omega\oplus x_1\oplus x_2\oplus\cdots)\otimes(1\Omega\oplus 0\oplus 0\oplus\cdots))=a\Omega\oplus x_1\oplus x_2\oplus\cdots$. Therefore, it unitary. But I want to compute what is the adjoint of $\phi$. Initially, I thought it would be $\phi^*(\xi)=\xi\otimes (1\Omega\oplus 0\oplus 0\cdots)$ for $\xi\in F(H)$.  But with this formula $\langle \phi^*(\xi),\eta\otimes\zeta)=0$ if the vaccum of $\zeta$ is $0$ i.e. the first component of $\zeta$ is $0$ for any $\xi$. That should not happen. There is something that I'm missing, but couldn't figure out. There is one doubt: is $\phi$ well-defined?

Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: $F(H)$ is a separable Hilbert space, $F(H)\otimes F(H)$ is a separable Hilbert space. Therefore, they are isomorphic. The question you probably want to ask: are they canonically isomorphic?

Comment: Yes. That's my question is. Like here is the map $\phi$ defines an unitary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(Disclaimer: I want to warn against a common mistake when dealing with tensor products, which is to forget that the tensor product is the (maybe closed) **linear span** of the elementary tensors. For some things one can comfortably work with elementary tensors, but for other things, like calculating norms, sums of elementary tensors cannot be avoided. Mentioning this as someone who made this mistake several times)*

Your $\phi$ is well-defined, as it is a linear extension of $$
(a\Omega\oplus x_1\oplus x_2\oplus\cdots)\otimes (0\oplus\cdots\oplus 0\oplus y_n\oplus0\oplus\cdots)\longmapsto (\overbrace{0\oplus\cdots\oplus 0}^n\oplus ay_n\oplus x_1\otimes y_n\oplus\cdots)
$$

There is an issue, though, which is how you see $F(H)\otimes F(H)$ as a Hilbert space. What I mean is that in general the inner product on the tensor product is defined as $$ \langle x\otimes y,z\otimes w\rangle=\langle x,z\rangle\langle y,w\rangle.$$ With this definition, your $\phi$ does not preserve the inner product. Indeed,
$$
\langle \phi((\Omega\otimes(0\oplus y)),\phi((0\oplus z)\otimes\Omega)\rangle=\langle 0\oplus y,0\oplus z\rangle=\langle y,z\rangle, 
$$
while
$$
\langle (\Omega\otimes(0\oplus y),(0\oplus z)\otimes\Omega\rangle=\langle \Omega\oplus0, 0\oplus z\rangle\langle 0\oplus y,\Omega\oplus0\rangle=0.
$$

But what you seem to be doing is to consider $F(H)$ as having an intrinsic tensor product, by which you have $F(H)\otimes F(H)=F(H)$ precisely via your $\phi$. The problem is that $\phi$ is not injective (and this is the mistake I mentioned at the beginning): for example
$$
\phi((0\oplus x_1)\otimes (0\oplus0\oplus x_1\otimes x_1))=0\oplus0\oplus0\oplus (x_1\otimes x_1\otimes x_1)=\phi((0\oplus0\oplus x_1\otimes x_1)\otimes (0\oplus x_1)).
$$
So the element $(0\oplus x_1)\otimes(0\oplus0\oplus x_1\otimes x_1)-(0\oplus0\oplus x_1\otimes x_1)\otimes (0\oplus x_1)$, which is not an elementary tensor, is in the kernel of $\phi$.

And this shows that problem with using $\phi$ to define the inner product on $F(H)\otimes F(H)$: what you get is not an inner product. If this is not the inner product you are using on $F(H)\otimes F(H)$, you need to tell us what you use.

Comment: Fun fact: To check the isometric property, it suffices to work with elementary tensors :)

Comment: That means that something I'm saying is wrong, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: I am not saying that  you said something wrong. I just wanted to share this sweet little fact that can save some time because it surprised me when I first discovered it.

Comment: Yes, but you need to be careful cause that's true for Hilbert spaces, but not for tensor norms in general. On a C$^*$-algebra, all norms on the tensor product agree on elementary tensors (they are all cross norms), but they can differ on the tensor product (that is, on sums of elementary tensors).

Comment: Yes, you are of course right.